# HTK: HVite can't find hmm

Tags: speech-recognition, htk

I want to build a speech recognition system using HTK and therefore downloaded a pre-trained acoustic model with tied states from http://www.keithv.com/software/htk/us/ (Training data: WSJ SI-84).

However, when I try to run HVite with my dictionary, I get the following error:

```
$ HVite -H macros -H hmmdefs -S test.scp -l '*' -i recout.mlf -w wdnet -p 0.0 -s 5.0 dict tiedlist  
ERROR [+8231]  GetHCIModel: Cannot find hmm [z-]ia[+r]
 FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HVite
```

where `macros`, `hmmdefs`, and `tiedlist` are the files downloaded from the link above. `test.scp` contains paths to my feature files.

My `dict` file looks like this:

```
DIAL d ay ax l
EIGHT ey t
FIVE f ay v
FOUR f ao r
NINE n ay n
OH ow
ONE w ah n
SENT-END [] sil
SENT-START [] sil
SEVEN s eh v ax n
SIX s ih k s
THREE th r iy
TWO t uw
ZERO z ia r ow
```

`wdnet` is generated using `HParse grammer wdnet`, where the content of `grammar` is the following:

```
$digit = ONE | TWO | THREE | FOUR | FIVE | SIX | SEVEN | EIGHT | NINE | OH | ZERO;

( SENT-START DIAL <$digit> SENT-END )
```

`tiedlist` does not have a line containing `z-ia+r`, but why is this an error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using phone names which are not match the phoneset of the acoustic model

```
 ZERO z ia r ow
```

must be

```
 ZERO z iy r ow
```

or

```
 ZERO z ih r ow
```

There is no such phone 'ia' in the phoneset

Comment: Oh no, this was way too obvious to check again. Thank you very much! However, I tried the model from keithv.com, because the one I had created didn't work for me and gave the same error message. Are there more causes of this message?